# How to add all cookies from previous cURL to next cURL

Tags: php, cookies

I have a PHP file that sends a cURL request to a web page, gets some cookies that should be set, and then sets the cookies in order to perform the next cURL request:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('https://www.roblox.com/newLogin');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    username => "EncodedLua",
    password => "", // Hidden
    submitLogin => "Log In"
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
$cookies = array();
$roblosecuritykey = "";

foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);

    // Set all of the returned cookies
}

curl_close($ch);

$ch2 = curl_init('https://www.roblox.com/groups/api/change-member-rank');
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    groupId => 2902455,
    newRoleSetId => 19777964,
    targetUserId => 55203439
));
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$result2 = curl_exec($ch2);

curl_close($ch2);
?>
```

I'm just not sure how to separate all of the cookies and then get the names and values by themselves. How would I do this?

Comment: Use the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put those cookies in the cookie jar:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('https://www.roblox.com/newLogin');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/home/me/mycookies");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    username => "EncodedLua",
    password => "", // Hidden
    submitLogin => "Log In"
));
```

Comment: I added the line "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "rbxcookies.txt");" after the CURL_RETURNTRANSFER line and it's not writing.

Comment: Actually, are cookies that I set on my site able to be accessed on other domains or do I have to specify that?

Comment: Cookies are domain-specific.  You can specify what domains cookies are to be used on, but you can't, for example, set cookies on Yahoo.com that are meant to be used on Google.com.

Use Firebug/Chrome Debugger and take a look at cookies from your site and others ... it might shed some light for you.